# iOS Rupee and @

Tags: ios, textfield

I am getting a whitespace when I enter rupee `'₹'` symbol and `'@'` in a secure-textfield.

My textfield.text reads proper, but a blank space is shown alternatively on the screen. If I keep entering `₹@₹@₹@`, my textfield has 6 characters, and textfield.text is `₹@₹@₹@`, but what it shows on UI is `₹ ₹ ₹`.

Please suggest

Comment: This is a secure text field right? Then how is it even displaying the text? Also, what font are you using?

Comment: It aint displaying the text as such. But the consecutive characters are shown with whitespace in between.